# LocalHost is not connecting while running the application in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, browser, localhost, visual-studio-2019

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 Community edition, version is 16.8.4. I have an application, while running that application, the Chrome browser is opening, after 1 or 2 minutes suddenly the browser is closing and the Visual Studio application stops running. I don't know what is happening, there are no errors displayed, it's just suddenly disconnecting.

Struggling to handle this situation, can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you get any error messages? Are there any related error messages in visual studio or in Event Viewer?

Comment: That usually is caused by IIS Express process exit. The Output panel in Visual Studio should contain enough information for you to get started.

Comment: Dear @Samwu I didn't get any error messages, simply disconnecting from both browser and application.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.